# HTML5 Audio Plays in IE but not Chrome

Tags: html, audio

I have added Audio to a webpage, to play once it loads, which works fine in Internet explorer but not in Google Chrome.

```
<audio autoplay>
   <source src="gears_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="gears.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
 Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I then added the following Javascript and gave the audio element the  ID audioId.  Again this worked perfectly in IE, but still nothing in Chrome, unless I Hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> keys together a couple of time and then chrome would play the audio file.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audioId");
audio.autoplay = true;
audio.load();
```

I have tried a host of code snipets and suggestions from various forums etc, but i just can't seem to get chrome to autoplay the audio.  If i add controls it is fine, it just wont autoplay.

UPDATE:
So i have discovered that if i load the page from a link then the audio plays, but if i just type in the URL of the page, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure on the reason why Chrome can be funny with autoplay. I tend not to trust it. This isn't really an answer for your question, but a work around for the problem.

Instead of using the `autoplay` attribute on the audio control. Use the `canplay` event on the element.

```
    var audio = document.getElementById("audioId");
    audio.oncanplay = function(){
        audio.play();
    }
    audio.load();
```

When the `canplay` event is fired, call `play()` on the audio element to start playing. You're creating your own auto play. Just remember unless you remove the event, any time the audio control loads a new file and can play the audio, the event gets fired. I tend to use this method to give me more flexability pre-playing the audio/video.